# Error message received when importing contacts into SalesForce for purpose of a campaign

Tags: error, campaign

I'm hoping this is an easy one, I've searched a few SF forums so far but not been able to find an answer that really seems suited to this exact situation.

I'm Adding members to a Campaign using Data Import Wizard with a CSV file containing 3 fields- Salesforce Contact ID, Campaign iD and Status (for campaign member status- Sent)

I have received an error message of: ENTITY_IS_DELETED:entity is deleted:--for all contacts I wanted to add to this particular campaign.

I googled that error message and mostly it appears to relate to deleted records in SF, but I have pulled all these contacts from a report in SF and when I type in individual Contact IDs to check I am seeing complete records, rather than receiving a message saying that record no longer exists.

Does anyone have any advice as to what could have possibly gone wrong here?

Thanks,

GT

Comment: Have you checked that campaign wasn't deleted?

Answer (score 1):

When I got this error message when I was using the Data Import Wizard, the problem was that the Salesforce IDs for the data I was trying to load pointed to records that didn't exist.

I was loading rows into a details/line items custom object, and the data I included for the master/header custom object, "a0xc00000029f9z", pointed to a record I had deleted.

I replaced the contents of my CSV with the correct Salesforce IDs and the import succeeded.